# Laravel 8: How to use helper class in model

Tags: laravel, model, helper

I think this seems clumsy. How do you suggest I use a helper class in my model when setting an attribute?

I want to avoid using static methods.

```
use App\Helpers\Tools;

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function setPhoneAttribute(string $value): void
    {
        $this->attributes['phone'] = (new Tools)->clean($value);
    }
}
```

This doesn't seemd to work:

```
use App\Helpers\Tools;

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function setPhoneAttribute(Tools $tools, string $value): void
    {
        $this->attributes['phone'] = $tools->clean($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are quite a few examples/tutorials on how to create and utilise custom helpers in Laravel. [Here is such an example](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way should be working without errors:

```
use App\Helpers\Tools;

class Customer extends Model
{
    public function setPhoneAttribute(string $value): void
    {
        $this->attributes['phone'] = (new Tools)->clean($value);
    }
}
```

the other code snippet is incorrect, `set{Column}Attribute` will only pass the `$value` argument.

you can create your own [helper function](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) or Facade to help you control the actual class/function performing the `clean` from one place.

Answer (score -1):

Inject in the helper class in the constructor.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explain what you mean through a small code example.